# Laravel pagination not working with array instead of collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I'm trying to paginate an array data set and it has proven more challenging than I thought.

I'm using Laravel 5

So I have an abstract interface/repository that all my other models extend to and I created a method inside my abstract repository call paginate.
I've included both

`use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;`

and

`use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;`

**Here is the method**

```
  public function paginate($items,$perPage,$pageStart=1)
    {

        // Start displaying items from this number;
        $offSet = ($pageStart * $perPage) - $perPage; 

        // Get only the items you need using array_slice
        $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($items, $offSet, $perPage, true);

        return new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($items), $perPage,Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(), array('path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()));
    }
```

So as you can imagine this function accepts an array of `$items` a `$perPage` variable that indicates how many to items to paginate and a `$pageStart` that indicates from which page to start.

The pagination works and I can see `LengthAwarePaginator` instance when I'm doing a `dd()` , all of it's values seem fine.

The problem starts when I'm displaying the results.

When I do `{!! $instances->render() !!}` The paginator links display's fine, the `page` parameter changes according to links but the data is not changing.
Data is the same in every page. When I'm using Eloquent for example `Model::paginate(3)` everything works fine, but when I `dd()` this `LengthAwarePaginator` it's identical to the `LengthAwarePaginator` instance of  my custom paginator with the exception that it paginates an array ofcourse and not a collection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not passing the current page, like you should so you also get same array. This will work

```
public function paginate($items,$perPage)
{
    $pageStart = \Request::get('page', 1);
    // Start displaying items from this number;
    $offSet = ($pageStart * $perPage) - $perPage; 

    // Get only the items you need using array_slice
    $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($items, $offSet, $perPage, true);

    return new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($items), $perPage,Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(), array('path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()));
}
```

Your function will also work if you pass correct value for `$pageStart` - `Request::get('page', 1)`