# How to get paginated data according to a array of ids in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```php
$ids = [4,3,1,2];
$result = DB::table('products')->where('status',1)->whereIn('id',$ids)->paginate(10);
```

So here the order of ids [4,3,1,2] in this same order i want paginate data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477915/laravel-pagination-not-working-with-array-instead-of-collection Look into this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got answer.

```
$ids = [4,3,1,2];

$ids_ordered = implode(',', $ids);

$result = DB::table('products')->where('status',1)->whereIn('id',$ids)->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered)"))->paginate(10);
```